# Why Azure QueueTriggered function app throwing Timeout exception?

Tags: azure, azure-function-app, queuetrigger

I have deployed a QueueTriggered function app on to Azure portal. But it seems like sometimes throwing Timeout exceeded exception. I got this error and thought of changing the functionTimeout value from 30 mins to 2 hrs. 
But still it's giving me the same error. My concern is, why QueueTrigger is throwing this error. It's job is to pass the message.
I am getting a blob name from queue message and passing it as a parameter to a Snowflake procedure to load that blob. Snowflake hardly takes a minute to load that blob. But why function app timeout is happening.
Error I am getting is :

```
Timeout value of 02:00:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.myFunctionAppName
Exception Type: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException
Failed method: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext
```

Call stack:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException:
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__29.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 665)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeAsync>d__27.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 576)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 532)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__25.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 470)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 278)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 325)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 117)
```

Code I developed using Python:

```
import logging
import json
import os
import snowflake.connector
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

# packages for reading blob (private key p8 file)
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions

# packages to decrypt private key
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import azure.functions as func


def execute_process(sourcecode, sourcefilename):
try:
    # storage connection string where Private Key p8 file is stored
    storage_conn = os.getenv("RsaStorage")
    # open service client to interact with storage
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
        storage_conn)
    # get blob stored in container get_blob_client(container,blob)
    file_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
        "access-files", "rsa/rsa_key.p8")
    # download blob to a variable
    f = file_client.download_blob()
    # get content of blob into key variable
    key = f._current_content
    # decrypt private key (obtained above) using private key password
    p_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key,
        password=os.environ["PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE"].encode(),
        backend=default_backend(),
    )
    # read private key bytes
    pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption(),
    )
    # create a Snowflake connection string
    conn = snowflake.connector.connect(user=os.getenv("user"),
                                       account=os.environ["account"],
                                       private_key=pkb,
                                       warehouse=os.environ["warehouse"],
                                       database=os.environ["database"],
                                       schema=os.environ["schema"],
                                       role=os.environ["role"])
    queryToExecute = ""
    # execute Snowflake query
    if sourcecode.upper() == "con1":
        queryToExecute = f"CALL Procedure1(NULL,'{sourcecode}','{sourcefilename}');"
    elif sourcecode.upper() == "con2":
        queryToExecute = f"CALL Procedure2(NULL,'{sourcecode}','{sourcefilename}');"
    elif sourcecode.upper() == "con3":
        queryToExecute = f"CALL procedure3(NULL,'{sourcecode}','{sourcefilename}');"
    if queryToExecute != "":
        for retMsg in conn.cursor().execute(queryToExecute):
            logging.info(
                "\nMessage returned from procedure : {0}".format(retMsg))
    else:
        logging.info(f"No query to execute for blob: {0}", sourcefilename)
except Exception as ex:
    raise Exception(ex)


def main(msg: func.QueueMessage) -> None:
try:
    result = json.loads(msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    subject = result["subject"]
    blob_name = subject[subject.rindex("/") + 1:]
    sourcefilename = subject[subject.index("incoming/"):]
    sourcecode = blob_name[blob_name.rindex(".") + 1:]
    logging.info('PharmacyDataLoader function started processing: %s',
                 blob_name)
    execute_process(sourcecode, sourcefilename)
    logging.info(f"completed PharmacyDataLoader function for {blob_name}")
except Exception as ex:
    logging.error(
        f"PharmacyDataLoader function failed to process {subject} with error {ex}"
    )
```

Any help to over come this issue?

Comment: can you please share relevant code of your Function? Also, when you say you increased the timeout to 2 hours, I assume you are not running in Consumption plan?!

Comment: I am using elastic premium plan. I can't share full code here. Sorry for that

Comment: hm but without seeing any code it is not really possible to say what could be going on

Comment: @silent, I added code sample I am running. I have increased time limit to 4 hours, but still same issue arises.

Comment: is your snowflake query actually returning? I.e. do you see any log messages after the query is supposed to be started?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function in premium plan supports guaranteed 60 minutes in [**`Premium Plan.`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) which you can try out.

However, i would recommend you to consider using the "Durable Functions" framework, which lets you split up your jobs into smaller junks.

Comment: I am running in Premium plan only. I had set functionTimeout to 4 hours yet same issue

Comment: as i mentioned premium is recommended for 60 minutes

Comment: @Sanjeetharan, I am using premium plan only.

Comment: No @Sajeetharan, please elaborate your suggestion.

Comment: I added 6 hours of functionTimeout, but I am not sure what wrong I am doing here, still problem persist.